# I not use click button for set ringtone and after for set notification when use getContentResolver().delete

Tags: android

When use

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
```

This code help me to delete list music from setting but
I am when click button for set ringtone and after click button for set notification not music set ringtone and notification.